# Working around private WAN IP with VPN?

Tags: vpn

So today i tried port forwarding on my RT-AC51U and found out that it doesnt work almost instantly. The problem is that my ISP doesnt provide me public WAN IP. The reason i wanted port forwarding was to connect via SSH to my home server.

But now im thinking about forgetting about port forwarding completely if this kind of setup could work: I set up VPS and VPN so that its private and only i can connect. I connect my server (Not router) to this VPN. Then from anywhere i connect my laptop or desktop or anything to the same VPN. Then SSH into the server.

Would this kind of setup be possible ? If so how could i do it ? If not whats the best alternative ? (Connecting router to VPN is not an option for me)

Comment: Yes it is certainly possible, but I have my modem in Bridge Mode and I do know the Public IP address (used in the router WAN setup)

Comment: I do not think Public IP adress would play a role in this setup as both devices are technically "clients". And IDK if bridge mode would have effect on it.

Comment: If you are trying to access the computer from outside the LAN (so outside the location of the computer) you would need the Public IP.  I assumed you wanted to do that.

Comment: Yes im trying to access the server from outside LAN. Thats why i asked if it would be possible to use VPS set up as VPN as basically the middle man of the communication.

Comment: I do that routinely but you need the address of the location you wish to access.

Comment: Found a much nicer solution. reverse ssh tunnel. Works great and there is no need to have second password when connecting

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using VPN a friend recommended me to look at reverse ssh tunnel. And that was exactly what i needed. Set it up and works amazingly well.